# Old Url will no longer be available, how to redirect to new URL in IIS?

Tags: domains, redirects, multiple-domains, iis

We currently have a site running of 2 URLs

- `OldSite.subdomain.domain.example`
- `newSite.newDomain.example`

There is the talk of getting rid of the 1st URL completely. Is there anything that can be done so that when the Old URL is entered into the browser they are redirected to the New URL.

Am I correct in assuming when the 1st URL is entered it will just 404 and Noting can be done from an IIS point of view to redirect.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of completely"?   Are you planning to let the domain registration lapse?  Or are you planning to retain control over the domain but just not have the content served at that domain?

Comment: The Domain Reg Will lapse. All traffic will now go to the new Url. Our concern is users who might have a Url bookmarked.

Comment: If you let the domain registration lapse, somebody else will likely buy the domain.  It will probably be used for spam or redirect to something undesirable.   The only way to keep bookmarks working is to retain control of the old domain.